# What's the difference between using and no using a "=" in Scala defs ?

Tags: scala

What the difference between the two `def`s below

```
def someFun(x:String) { x.length }
```

AND

```
def someFun(x:String) = { x.length }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others already pointed out, the former is a syntactic shortcut for

```
def someFun(x:String): Unit = { x.length }
```

Meaning that the value of `x.length` is discarded and the function returns `Unit` (or `()` if you prefer) instead.

I'd like to stress out that **this is deprecated** since Oct 29, 2013 (https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3076/), but the warning only shows up if you compile with the `-Xfuture` flag.

```
scala -Xfuture -deprecation

scala> def foo {}
<console>:1: warning: Procedure syntax is deprecated. Convert procedure `foo` to method by adding `: Unit =`.
       def foo {}
foo: Unit
```

So you **should never use** the so-called procedure syntax.
Martin Odersky itself pointed this out in his [Scala Day 2013 Keynote](http://www.parleys.com/play/51c1994ae4b0d38b54f4621b/chapter47/about) and it has been discussed in the [scala mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/q1YX7NC1geM/discussion).

The syntax is very inconsistent and it's very common for a beginner to hit this issue when learning the language. For this reasons it's very like that it will be removed from the language at some point.

Answer (score 6):

Without the equals it is implicitly typed to return Unit (or "void"): the result of the body is fixed - not inferred - and any would-be return value is discarded.

That is, `def someFun(x:String) { x.length }` is *equivalent* to `def someFun(x:String): Unit = { x.length }`, neither of which are very useful here because the function causes no side-effects and returns no value.

The "equals form" without the explicit Unit (or other type) has the return type inferred; in this case that would be `def someFun(x:String): Int = { x.length }` which is more useful, albeit not very exciting.

---

I prefer to specify the return type for all exposed members, which helps to ensure API/contract stability and arguably adds clarity. For "void" methods this is trivial done by using the Procedure form, without the equals, although it is a stylistic debate of which is better - opponents might argue that having the different forms leads to needless questions about such ;-)

Comment: The procedure syntax is officially deprecated, although the warning only shows up with the `-Xfuture` flag enabled. The warning will be likely made explicit in future versions and the whole syntax will be eventually removed at some point, so I'd strongly advise against using it.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Interesting, I didn't know it was deprecated. I sort of like(d) it.

Answer (score 3):

The former is

```
def someFun(x: String): Unit = {
  x.length
  ()  // return unit
}
```

And the latter is

```
def someFun(x: String): Int = {
  x.length  // returned
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [Scala Style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/?_ga=1.147515902.890376456.1404536324) always recommend using '`=`', both in

- [method declaration](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html)

> Methods should be declared according to the following pattern:

```
def foo(bar: Baz): Bin = expr
```

- [function declaration](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html)

> Function types should be declared with a space between the parameter type, the arrow and the return type:

```
def foo(f: Int => String) = ...
def bar(f: (Boolean, Double) => List[String]) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As per **Scala-2.10**, using equals sign is preferred. Infact you must use equals sign in call declarations except the definitions returning Unit.

As such there is no difference but the first one is not recommended anymore and it should not be used.

Comment: Hasn't this always (since at least 2.7) been the case? :>

Comment: @user2864740:- Indeed!