# Scala compile time error while calling a method by passing List[Record]

Tags: scala

I am doing some basic handson in scala.. i am getting compile-time error at the place of defining a method called processList.

The compile time error is

```
 Multiple markers at this line:
- only classes can have declared but undefined 
 members
```

My code is as follows,

```
package pack1

import scala.io.Source

case class Record(id:Int, name:String, city:String)

object ReadingFile {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fileLoc:String = "/home/edureka/surender/inputfiles/records.txt"

    val fileData:List[String] = Source.fromFile(fileLoc).getLines().toList

    val fileList =fileData.map { eachLine => {
      val Array(a:String,b:String,c:String) = eachLine.split(",")
      Record(a.toInt,b,c)
    } } 

    println(fileList)

    processList(fileList)

  } 

  def processList(myList:List[Record]) 

  {

  }

}
```

I dont know how to fix this, Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the new line after `def processList(myList:List[Record])` Scala compiler thinks that the method implementation is not given and below block `{}` does not belong to the method. So compiler thinks its a abstract method.

Declare `processList` like this

```
 def processList(myList:List[Record]) {

 }
```

or

```
 def processList(myList:List[Record]): Unit = {

 }
```

Instead of this

```
def processList(myList:List[Record])
                                     //remove this line to fix the error
   {

   }
```

Comment: the syntax you suggest is deprecated. Use `: Unit = { }` instead.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847386/whats-the-difference-between-using-and-no-using-a-in-scala-defs/24851910#24851910

Comment: @GabrielePetronella sure ..thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this code is here,

```
def processList(myList:List[Record]) 
                         // <------ Notice this blank line
{

}
```

This leads the compiler to think that these are two different statements. And hence it thinks that you have left `def processList(myList:List[Record])` without providing an implementation. And a `class` or `case class` and `object` can not have un-implemented members.

So... just fix that,

```
def processList(myList:List[Record]): Unit = {
}
```

Comment: Which noble lord thought of down-voting an answer without providing any reason ?