# Scala Assert Testing Expectations

Tags: scala

I am creating some tests in Scala and am trying to better understand some behavior I am seeing.

When I write my method as so, with a return Type, my test passes.

```
def cube(x: Int): Int ={
        x * x * x
    }
```

```
test("CubeTest") {
    assert(CubeCalculator.cube(3) === 27)
  }
```

However, when I do not specify the return type the test fails:

```
def cube(x: Int){
        x * x * x
    }
```

I was under the impression that The Scala compiler can infer return types for methods so why do I need to state it for the test to pass?

Comment: _"I do not specify the return type the test fails"_ it may help if you can explain why / how it fails? - _"I was under the impression that The Scala compiler can infer return types for methods"_ yes it is, although a common best practice is to always used explicit return types, it helps the compiler, it reduces bugs, it serves as documentation, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using and no using a "=" in Scala defs ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847386/whats-the-difference-between-using-and-no-using-a-in-scala-defs)

Answer (score 0):

Omitting the return type isn't the problem with your code, it's omitting the `=` sign.

```scala
def cube(x: Int){
  x * x * x
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```scala
def cube(x: Int): Unit = {
  x * x * x
}
```

Since a `Unit` cannot possibly be an `Int`, the comparison in your test cannot pass; presumably the `===` is a "typesafe equality operator" which prevents impossible comparisons like this from compiling.

This syntax for defining `Unit`-resulting methods is dropped in Scala 3.

It's worth noting what exactly this procedure does:

- It  calculates `x * x * x`
- It throws away that result and returns the singleton value of `Unit`: `()`

This throwing away of the result is at the very least wasteful; there's a compiler option which makes such discarding of a value a warning: `-Ywarn-discard`.  With this option in force, you would have to write

```scala
def cube(x: Int) {
  x * x * x
  ()
}
```

Which at least makes it clear that you want `x * x * x` computed and thrown away.

```scala
def cube(x: Int) = x * x * x
```

Should have an inferred result type of `Int`.  That said, using an explicit return type on (at least) externally visible non-constant methods may serve a useful documentation function, improve compiler speed, and prevent situations where you think you're returning one type but are actually returning another.